# Нужно создать поле для ввода текста которое будет автоматически увеличиваться вместе с набранным текстом (по высоте)

Tags: javascript, css, text, resize

Нужно создать поле для ввода текста которое будет автоматически увеличиваться вместе с набранным текстом (по высоте). Использовать textarea нельзя, тк там есть странный угол который никак не вписывается в дизайн.

Подобная вещь реализована в [telegra.ph](http://telegra.ph).

Comment: При удалении символов поле должно уменьшатся обратно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы убрать странный угол, задайте [resize: none](http://htmlbook.ru/css/resize)

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
// Учитываем padding
const padding = textarea.offsetHeight - textarea.clientHeight;

textarea.oninput = e => {
    // Схлопываем
    textarea.style.height = 'auto';
    // Расхлопываем
    textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + padding + 'px';
}
```

```css
textarea{
  resize: none; /* Убираем "Странный угол" */
}
```

```html
<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>
```

Comment: Поле должно расти не постоянно, а только тогда когда строка заполняется.

Comment: @brachkoff Так вроде так оно и есть

Comment: @brachkoff у меня так и происходит. Какой у вас браузер?

Comment: странно, все стало работать. Спасибо.

Comment: @Darth можете закинуть код на jsfiddle.net тк не понятно куда именно вы вставляли js. Кроме того если стереть текст поле почему то остается того же размера.

Comment: @brachkoff обновил ответ, теперь сжимаецо обратно и padding можно не убирать

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contenteditable</title>
  <style>
    div.d1 {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d1">
    <div contenteditable="true">This is a sample</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```